# Implementation of class data validation

Tags: c#, validation, serialization, correctness

I have an object that represents physics characteristics of some air tunnel:

```
public class Tunnel
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double CrossSectionArea { get; set; }
    public double AirDensity { get; set; }
    public double Pressure { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I need to check correctness of parameters: for example, Length must be `> 0`, Pressure `>= 0` and so on. The first idea was just to put checking to property accessor and throw exception on invalid data:

```
public class Tunnel
{
    private double length;
    public double Length
    {
        get { return length; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
                throw new TunnelParametersException("Invalid data");
            length = value;
        }
        //...
    }
```

But I have a collection of such object and it will be serialized/deserialized to/from XML-file. So the problem is that it will not work with serialization (if I'm not mistaken). User can edit file and enter whatever he want and I will not able to catch it.

So, as I understand, need to create some function (in `Tunnel` class or in another one) that I will call to check that all values are correct. But here another problem: `Tunnel` can have few invalid parameters. How should I return errors and process them? The program must return all found errors in one call. And this way is good for only my own use of classes. I probably can't obligate another programmer to use validation after every editing of data.

Give me please an advice how would be more correct to implement such checking of values and solve my problem - maybe some another flexible way so would be easy to manage and improve this code in the future. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Returning to my first idea, is there any way to validate data during or after serialization?

Comment: I don't know how the actual serialization works. But don't you want to do a check when the xml gets converted to an object, so the serialization fails when the input is not correct?

Comment: How are you deserializing it? Do you call a static Deserialize method on the Tunnel class?

Comment: I'm going to write it something like in this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization). I'm actually new to this question, but have read that this process just restore all private members without calling properties accessors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest possible way:

```
//Returns empty list if no errors.
public List<TunnelErrors> Validate()
{
    //Validate params
}
```

Comment: A good way but only for my own use. How can I oblige another programmer to call this method after any editing of class members or deserialization?

Comment: To my previous question, probably I just need to write one function that will do both things: deserialize and validate. So result will be always correct.

Answer (score 1):

What comes into my mind is this.

I would keep a readonly IsValid property. On the getter I would do all my validation and say true or false.

In any place where I use the object I would would check to see if the object.IsValid is true.

Answer (score 1):

try making your files pass through a wrapper function everytime, and making the files on disk read-only for normal user,i.e, if the user has to edit the file he does so only through your program, when the user is finished editing u pass all the data through your function to see if the whole data is still valid or not,

Comment: Forbidding file editing with open format and writing additional program is not a good idea... Writing wrapper function is a way.

Answer (score 1):

For the edit : make the serialization streams pass through a sort-of buffer function,that processes the data before serialization or during it, depending on which way is easier to implement, if you chose the former, the data will first be validated(the return type and parameter type will be same) and then be serialized, otherwise the data will be checked as it is converted..